# Using $(this) and sum on an .append to multiply fields and get a total sum with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add the functionality to this dynamic order form that will auto sum the field data. 
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish...[image]

The form works like this...
field1 is setup with .autocomplete with $(this) to .append a new line. It adds a new line when you .focusin on the qty field. I would like to add the functionality of adding all the dynamically generated lines to add the subTotals and then add all the subTotals to the orderTotal.

### HERE'S MY CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include '../_includes/jq.inc.php';?>

</head>
<body>

<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<hr>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="orderForm">
<table class="orderLine" >
 <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">field1<br><input class="field1" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#999999">field4<br><input type="text" class="field4" size="15"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">qty<br><input class="qty addLine" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#999999">subTotal<br><input class="subTotal" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><button class="OFDeleteButton">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div><br>

<table width="434" >
  <tr>
    <td width="482">orderTotal<input id="orderTotal" type="text" size="15"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<input name="" type="submit" value="Place Order">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.field1').val("");
$('.field4').val("");

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.field1').live({
        focusin: function() {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: "PRODUCT.ORDER.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                autoFocus: true,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    $tr.find('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
                    $tr.find('.field4').val(ui.item.field4);
                    }
                })
                }
            });
        }); 
});

$("#orderForm").delegate(".OFDeleteButton", "click", function () {
    $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});
<!-- This removes all newLine table rows -->
     $("#removeAll").click(function () {
      $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

<!-- ADDS the 'newLine' table rows -->
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.qty').live({
        change: function() {
            $('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine"><tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">field1<br><input class="field1" type="text" size="15"></td><td bgcolor="#999999">field4<br><input type="text" class="field4" size="15"></td><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">qty<br><input class="qty addLine" type="text" size="15"></td><td bgcolor="#999999">subTotal<br><input class="subTotal" type="text" size="15"></td><td><button class="OFDeleteButton">Delete</button></td></tr></table>');
            }
        })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do in order to add the fields the way I want and have it work dynamically as new lines are added or removed. Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

Here's what I have on it right now...

```
$(function(e) {
    $('.subTotal').live({
        focusin: function() {
            updateTotal();
            }
        })
});
```

I intend on "disabling" the subTotal field so it can not be altered. So what would I use to replace the focusin on the subTotal to make the function() run? Is there somthing other than change that would work??

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you encounter difficulty? What is your question? (Please be specific.)

Comment: You'll want to use the `.change()` event handler. Attach it to each input field (preferably all of them at once) and have it update your total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `change` event handler for `.qty`, you could find the the corresponding price, and calculate the subtotal. Given that it is bound using `.live()`, it should apply to new rows as they are created.

```
var qty = $(this).val();
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var price = $('.field4:eq(0)', $tr).val();
var subTotal = parseFloat(qty * price) || 0;
$('.subTotal:eq(0)', $tr).val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
updateTotal();
```

Where `updateTotal` is a function that updates the order total.

```
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.subTotal').each(function() { total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0; });
    $('#orderTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's about what I was looking for. What would be the best way for me to add the updateTotal(); to be more automatic? Like maybe on the subTotal.val() change?

Comment: @Monty Well, where you call `updateTotal()` is a matter of your organization. Note, though, that attaching it to the `change` event of the `.subTotal` won't automatically call it when you change the subtotals using `.val()`. You would have to manually `.trigger('change')`. Personally, I like how I did it ;).

Comment: @Monty I guess I don't quite follow your edit. What is wrong with having `updateTotal` run whenever a quantity field is changed?

Comment: Nothing. That works totally fine. I just messed it up! I also added the updateTotal() to the delete line function! Thanks for all your help! One other thing... on the subTotal fields and the orderTotal field what do I do get the decimal right for money?